# Set values in dataframe A by iterating from values on dataframe B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe A is similar to this :

```
info2 = {'speed': [None]*80}
dfA = pd.DataFrame(info2)
dfA
```

[image]

Dataframe B is similar to this :

```
info={"IndexSpeed":[7,16,44,56,80],"speed":[25,50,25,50,90]}
dfB = pd.DataFrame(info)
dfB
```

[image]

I need to set the values in dfA['speed'] by using the values in dfB.
For instance, for each row in dfA of index <=7, speed should be set at 25.
for each row of index between 8 and 16, speed should be set at 50. and so on untill all 80 rows are set.

What would be the optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
dfA['speed'] = pd.merge_asof(dfA.drop(columns='speed'), dfB,
                             left_index=True, right_on='IndexSpeed',
                             direction='forward',
                             )['speed']
```

*NB. dfA must be sorted on its index and dfB on IndexSpeed.*

Output:

```
    speed
0      25
1      25
2      25
3      25
4      25
..    ...
75     90
76     90
77     90
78     90
79     90

[80 rows x 1 columns]
```

Output as array:

```
array([25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
       25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25,
       25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
       50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90,
       90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a dict with keys corresponding to tuples with two components

```
zipped = zip(pd.concat([pd.Series(0),dfB.IndexSpeed + 1]),dfB.IndexSpeed))
ind_mapper = {(i,j): k for (k,(i,j)) in enumerate(zipped)}

for lower, upper in ind_mapper:
    dfA.iloc[lower:upper,0] = dfB.iloc[index_mapper[(lower, upper)],1]
```